# Remove Dialog and go back to previous activity while parsing data using AsyncTask ,when clicking Back button

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, back

i'm using AsyncTask to retrive data from RSS ,,i'm showing a progress Dialog in onpreExecute method,,parse Data in the DoInbackground method,,,and Removing the Dialog,,,showing the data in onPostExecute method,,every thing is ok..but i want to handle the backbutton ,,so if the user clicked the back button while parsing the data,he can go back..but until now if i pressed back nothing happen..:/

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        feedParser = new activity1Parser(Bean.LINK);

        try {
            list = feedParser.parse();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            activity1.removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your dialog (in `onCreateDialog`), make it cancelable and call `setOnCancelListener` with a listener that notifies your task that the dialog has been removed. Then in `onPostExecute`, remove the dialog only if it has not been removed.

Comment: exactly. the dialog by default consumes the back button press, so you cannot just override onBackPressed in your activity.

Comment: i tried this code with many classes and it worked...but in one of them  it keeps showing me a NullPointerException in onPostExcute Method at android.os.AsyncTask.Finish

Comment: @Reham Please post this NPE problem as a new question, including the code for `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I did..
@TedHopp ...this is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638265/null-pointer-exception-when-trying-to-cancel-progress-dialog-in-asynctask-in-and
if you can help me