# Null Pointer exception when trying to cancel Progress Dialog in AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

I'm Getting a Null Pointer Exception while canceling the Progress Dialog in Async Task ..this is my code..I'm Getting Data from an RSS Conecction for 7 days of Week..I want to cancel the Dialog and stop the task if the user pressed Back Button.

```
          @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
        Calendar calendar = null;
        switch (day) {
            case SAT:
                calendar = DateUtil.getSaturdayDate();
                break;
            case SUN:
                calendar = DateUtil.getSundayDate();
                break;
            case MON:
                calendar = DateUtil.getMondayDate();
                break;
            case TUE:
                calendar = DateUtil.getTuesdayDate();
                break;
            case WED:
                calendar = DateUtil.getWednesdayDate();
                break;
            case THU:
                calendar = DateUtil.getThursdayDate();
                break;
            case FRI:
                calendar = DateUtil.getFridayDate();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(calendar != null) {
            generatedLink = WeeklyScheduleBean.generatePath( DateUtil.getDay(calendar),
                                                             DateUtil.getMonth(calendar),
                                                             DateUtil.getYear(calendar) );
        } else {
            // get the schedule of today
            Calendar current_day = DateUtil.getCurrentTime();
            generatedLink = WeeklyScheduleBean.generatePath( DateUtil.getDay(current_day),
                                                             DateUtil.getMonth(current_day),
                                                             DateUtil.getYear(current_day) );
        }
    }

        @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        feedParser = new WeeklyScheduleParser(generatedLink);
        list = new ArrayList<WeeklyScheduleBean>();
        try {
            list = feedParser.parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }           

        if(list.size() > 0)                             
            return true;
        else 
            return false;           
    }



        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
        if(result) {
            weeklyScheduleScreen.removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
            adapter = new WeeklyAdapter(cxt, R.layout.time_text_list, R.id.title_text, list);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 
        else {
            DialogUtil.CreateDialog("", "Could not retreive the feeds",false,WeeklyScheduleScreen.this);
            weeklyScheduleScreen.removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you define weeklyScheduleScreen ??

Comment: WeeklyScheduleScreen is the screen which contains this code.

Comment: can you paste logs here with exception,

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(24962): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(24962):at com.view.WeeklyScheduleScreen$WeeklyScheduleTask.onPostExecute(WeeklyScheduleScreen.java:194)

E/AndroidRuntime(24962): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)

E/AndroidRuntime(24962):at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)

Comment: it is showing error in WeeklyScheduleScr‌​een.java at line number 194, see what value can be null at this line. May be u missed something.

Comment: weeklyScheduleScreen.removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);

at this line...but really i don't know what i'm missing
do you know another way for canceling the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);` to `progressDialog.show();`

Comment: This would prevent the dialog from being managed properly through the activity life cycle in the event of a configuration change.

Comment: can you explain your answer and help me solving this..please

Comment: you start one dialog instanse and then try to call isShowing() function from another

Comment: Thank you all..:)
I used the same code but i was creating an instance of the Dialog 2 times..My fault.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `weeklyScheduleScreen` anywhere. Also, since `showDialog` can be called without any object, my guess is that this AsyncTask is nested within your activity class. In that case, you don't need `weeklyScheduleScreen`. Just change it to `removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);` (without the `weeklyScheduleScreen.`).

Answer (score 0):

You should check : `

```
if (isCancelled())
```

within your AsyncTask methods and you should think about overriding the onCancelled method
of AsyncTask to dismiss your progress dialog at the right time.